# Compact Complex n-folds with Betti numbers $b_1=b_2=b_n=0$ for $n >3$

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Are there known examples of compact complex n-dimensional manifolds with betti numbers $b_1=b_2=b_n=0$ for $n >3$?  (The case of $n=3$ is the question of integrable complex structures on homology 6-spheres.)

Comment: Compact?  Obviously there are non-compact examples.

Comment: Yes, I should have put in compact.

Comment: @Andrew McHugh:  Am I missing something?  Isn't the $n=3$ case the question of whether a *homology* $6$-sphere admits a complex structure?  Or is a homology $6$-sphere admitting a complex structure automatically $S^6$?

Comment: I think you are right.  I should have said homology 6-sphere instead of topological $S^6$.  I believe it is still a well known open question as to whether $S^6$ has an integrable complex structure.  

Comment: I edited the question to specify compact.  

Comment: @Andrew McHugh:  Indeed, that is a well-known open question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The product of two spheres of odd dimensions admits a complex structure (Calabi-Eckmann)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Eckmann_manifold

Comment: yes, but it won't satisfy the OP's condition on the Betti numbers!

Comment: oops, I guess I read the OP's condition as $b_1=b_2=b_3=...=b_n=0$, which is apparently not what was asked!

Comment: Right $-$ it's enough for the odd dimensions to be distinct (and neither equal $1$).

Comment: Yes. provided I am answering indeed the question Andrew had in mind.

Comment: @Dmitri,  Yes, this answers my question.  Thank you!
