# Is there a compact complex manifold with $b_1(X)=b_2(X)=b_3(X)=b_4(X)=0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

As the title suggests, I have the following question:

> Is there a compact complex manifold with $b_1(X)=b_2(X)=b_3(X)=b_4(X)=0$?

Clarification:

Denote by $b_k$ the $k$th Betti number of a compact complex manifold of positive dimension.

Comment: Do you mean Betti numbers? The point seems to work.

Comment: I think the answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117098/compact-complex-n-folds-with-betti-numbers-b-1-b-2-b-n-0-for-n-3?rq=1 applies here as well.

Comment: @dhy Is there an example in complex dimension $3$? It doesn't seem to work for $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^5$.

Comment: In dimension 3 an example would be a homology $\Bbb{Q}$-sphere. This is very close to ask whether $\Bbb{S}^6$ admits a complex structure...

Comment: I guess that an irreducible locally symmetric space has vanishing of Betti numbers below the rank (or so)? If so, irreducible locally symmetric Hermitian space of large enough rank would work. Hopefully somebody will confirm, as the literature looks quite arid to me.

Comment: There are infinitely many six-dimensional rational homology spheres which admit almost complex structures (and infinitely many which do not), but as far as I know, it is unknown whether any of them admit a complex structure. Aside from dimension two, rational homology spheres in every other dimension cannot even admit an almost complex structure.

Comment: @YCor Unless I'm mistaken, a compact  Hermitian locally symmetric space would be Kähler, so $b_2$ would be positive.

Comment: @DonuArapura oops, indeed you're right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are complex manifolds with reduced cohomology vanishing in arbitrarily high degrees. Namely, product of two odd-dimensional spheres admits complex structure coming from representing it as a quotient of $(\Bbb C^n \setminus {0})\times (\Bbb C^m \setminus {0})$ by diagonal action of $\Bbb C$. They are known as Calabi-Eckmann manifolds.

Easiest example is $(\Bbb C^n \setminus {0})\times (\Bbb C^m \setminus {0}) / (e^At, e^At)$, where $A$ is a scalar matrix with non-real value $a$. It maps to a product of complex projective spaces by further quotiening, giving it structure of principal bundle with fiber being elliptic curve $\Bbb C / (\Bbb Z\cdot 1, \Bbb Z \cdot a)$. This map is the algebraic reduction of the manifold.

This easy example admits deformations of several types; for example, you can take different contracting flow instead of linear diagonal one. Most deformations do not have complex submanifolds at all, and have algebraic dimension zero as "most" generic complex manifolds.

Comment: This example was already brought up by dhy in the comments (by linking to Dmitri Panov's answer to another question)